# Looking for a good info on unit testing in Java

Tags: java, junit, junit4

For people who write unit tests already, but not necessarily doing it right :), sort of "Dos and Donts" list if there is one

Answer (score 2):

Hi found this post a while back i hope it will be helpful [Writing Great Unit Tests: Best and Worst Practices](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the things I followed in reference to junit:

Do's

1. Make your individual test case as small as possible
2. Create new object of the class whose functionality you are about to test.
3. Use assertXXXX() and not just assert() as the later works by enabling the '-ea' option at command line.

Don't

1. Don't name you class 'Test' because if you use the annotation the eclipse will confuse it with your Test class instead of the org.junit.Test
2. Don't code 
   `assertTrue(list1.equals(list2))`
   it is better and efficient to code the same thing this way
   `assertEquals(list1, list2)`. They differ in the output message they produce.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this book could help you: [Beautiful Testing Leading Professionals Reveal How They Improve Software](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596159825.do). It's not about JUnit but testing in general.